# Биеннале или бьеннале?

Tags: орфография

Вообще, я всегда считал, что правильно писать "биеннале" (выставка камерной акварели, проводящаяся раз в два года), и так же пишут в газетах и на афишах. Но Ворд при проверке подчеркнул мне это как ошибку и предложил вариант "бьеннале" — через мягкий знак.
А как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово итальянского происхождения, "biennale", т.е., "каждые два года", "раз в два года". Я живу в Италии и осмелюсь заметить, что итальянцы звуки зазря не проглатывают. Я бы сказала, наоборот, особенность итальянского языка заключается в правиле "как пишется, так и слышится", и неважно, если слог под ударением или нет, произносится ровно так, как написано. Мне лично вариант "биеннале" представляется более естественным. Во втором варианте есть что-то от искаженного французского, ни то, ни се. Но спорить не буду, возможно, русский язык принял оба варианта на равных правах.

Comment: Не знаю. Сейчас, помимо двух в моём ответе, на Ю-тюбе прослушал ещё несколько вариантов произнесения итальянцами этого слова - везде произносят [б'ьjэна:л'э], где "ь" - редуцированный гласный переднего ряда, а ":" - ударение (у итальянцев оно скорее долгое, нежели ударное).  
Возможно итальянцы "i" произносят крайне коротко и русскому ухо она воспринимается, скорей как апостроф, или у меня проблемы со слухом, но если б решил записать как произносят слово итальянцы, написал именно "бьенале".

Comment: Сочетание "ie" здесь - это hiatus по латыни (итал. iato, т.е пробел). К сожалению, не знаю, как это правильно называется по-русски (инженеры мы, не филологи :-), простите великодушно) В этом случае "i" и "e" произносятся как независимые гласные - "иэ". По-другому было бы, если б мы имели дело с дифтонгом, т.е. с сочетанием слабой (i) и сильной (е) гласных. Вот тогда действительно звук "i" был бы почти неуловим и мог бы быть условно выражен как "ь".

Comment: Я бы еще добавила, что произносится это слово как [биэнна'ле], но это так, для кучи... чтоб окончательно все запутать :-)

Comment: Да, то, что [э], а не [jэ] я потом сам услышал, но уже поздновато было. Спасибо за интересный ответ.

По-русски "hiatus" - зияние. Может как раз потому что в русском зияния нет, и появился вариант с мягким знаком, или заимствовано не с итальянского.

Comment: (..и на этих словах все инженеры, проживающие в Италии, надулись от гордости и даже покраснели от усилий и от собственной значимости :-)))

Answer (score 1):

И так и так. Эти варианты равноправны. (см. [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E1%FC%E5%ED%ED%E0%EB%E5&all=x)).

Самое известное бьеннале Венецианское и слово изначально скорей всего пришло оттуда, а итальянцы [и] в этом слове проглатывают. Можете прослушать [здесь](http://ru.forvo.com/word/biennale_di_venezia/#it) или [здесь](http://ru.forvo.com/word/biennale/#it). Как следствие бьеннале - вариант "как слышится" , а биенале - "как пишется"